# Tricky representations of many particle / many-body systems?

Tags: many-body

Usually many-particle system is represented by the set of variables {$p_1, q_1, s_1, ..., p_n, q_n, s_n$). Sometimes there is representation by the spin glasses (not much different). Then there is special representation for crystals, whose symmetries and regularities allow to consider one cell. Then there is statistical continuums used in thermodynamics. What are there any other, interesting, tricky representations for many-particle systems. E.g. one can consider density function $f(x, y, z)$, which can have large values around the point of particle and smaller values outside it. Then there is second quantization with creation and annihilation operators. Actually, this is the quantum wave function. But still, maybe there are other representations that can make the problem of many particle system possible to handle? What about high-energy jets?

I am trying to model neural networks and I hope to find inspiration in the physics of many particle systems. I would not like to discuss how such analogy can work out, just wanted to know more about ways of representing many-particle systems.

I am currently studying "Statistical field theory for neural networks" https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.10416 and I will see where it brings me, it is quite long memo.

Comment: May I ask what is wrong with the usual model of neural networks (which each interconnection layer is modeled as a matrix)? Certainly there are some limitations in that model, but what in particular do you want to generalize?

Comment: I want to research the emergent phenomena, collective behavior (like collective quasiparticle excitations in condensed matter) that can represent the emergence of concepts, visual features, language actions and so on. More or less it is about neural coding - how knowledge graph of concepts is represented by set of neurons and synapses. I know only very few and essentially non-inspiring articles about this, usual neuron models are lacking something to research such emergent phenomena and dynamics. Physics - in opposite - have this experience.